# Is it possible to create an object of an interface in java?

Tags: java, interface, instance, anonymous-class

In java, an interface contains only the method type, name and parameters. The actual implementation is done in a class that implements it. Given this, how is it possible to create an instance of a interface and use it as if it were a class object? There are many such interfaces, such as [org.w3c.dom.Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html).

This is the code that I am using:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory fty = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
fty.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = fty.newDocumentBuilder();
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes());
Document xmldoc = builder.parse(bais);
NodeList rm1 = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("Subject");
Node rm3 = rm1.item(0);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You never create an instance of *just* the interface. You can have a field/parameter/local variable of that interface type, but that's fine - the value that is assigned to such a variable will always be either null or a reference to an instance of some concrete implementation of the interface. The point is that code which deals only with the interface shouldn't need to care what the implementation is.

A good example is [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) - I can provide that any list implementation, and it will only use the methods declared in the interface. The *actual object* will always be an instance of some concrete implementation, but the `shuffle` method doesn't need to know or care.

Comment: are saying that the "node"(in the link) that I am using is actually implemented somewhere in some class. And I am using an istance of that class?

Comment: But where is the implementation provided?

Comment: @Ashwin: We can't possibly know without seeing what you're trying to use. If you're *specifically* talking about the `Node` interface, then it will typically depend on the implementation you'll have grabbed with `DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance`. Usually, you shouldn't care - if you're given an interface, just use the methods within it.

Comment: okay.. yeah I was talking about node only. So DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance returns an implementation of Node?

Comment: @Ashwin: No - look at the declaration - but that's one typical route for getting into the XML API, which is *very* heavily interface-based. So you'd often use `DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument()` which will give you a `Document` implementation, which you'd then use to add extra elements etc. It's not really clear what you're really trying to find out at this point...

Comment: Basically I am asking that which is the class that implements Node

Comment: I have edited and put my code. At which point the implementation of node is there.

Comment: @Ashwin: Well first you're getting a `DocumentBuilderFactory` implementation - which means you're getting an implementation of an abstract class. Then you're getting an implementation of `DocumentBuilder` - another abstract class. Then *that's* providing an implementation of `Document` within `builder.parse`, and the `Document` provides a `NodeList` when you call `getElementsByTagName`. As soon as you've got a `DocumentBuilderFactory`, that's basically going to determine which whole "DOM API" implementation you're using.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Please correct me if I am wrong. DocumentBuilderFactory has the implementation for DocumentBuilder, Node, Document etc.

Comment: @Ashwin: DocumentBuilderFactory is abstract - its `newInstance` static method takes various steps to determine which implementation (of DocumentBuilderFactory) to load. That class doesn't *itself* implement the Node, Document (etc) interfaces - but it knows enough to give you back a DocumentBuilder implementation when you ask for one. That in turn knows enough to create a Document implementation etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to get a usable interface class. 
If we have the interface:

```
public interface Vehicle{
    public void drive();
}
```

The first is, as you say to have a class which implements the interface:

```
public class Car implements Vehicle{
    public void drive(){
        System.out.println("Here in my car I feel safest of all);
    }
}
Vehicle car = new Car();
v.drive();
```

Or you can create an anonymous class:

```
Vehicle v = new Vehicle(){
    public void drive(){
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
};
v.drive();
```

Comment: okay..But then what is happening here. NodeList nodelist1=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("Subject"); Node node1=rm1.item(0);  node1.getFirstChild().setNodeValue(suserid); . Where is the implementation for node1?

Comment: @Ashwin The code you are calling will be using a particular implementation. This will be created at some point (either during the creation of the Document or during the call to getElementsByTagName.

Comment: @Ashwin Essentially, it shouldn't matter. All your code should care about is that it is a `Node` Not what kind of `Node` it is. If you are just curious however you can use: `node1.getClass().getName()` to find out the class name of the implementing class.

Answer (score 2):

You don't create an Instance of the interface - you create an instance of a class which implements the interface. You can create as many different implementations as you like and choose the one which fits best.

In your code you can use a implementation where an object conforming to the interface is required.

Answer (score 1):

The interface is a special class with an abstract type so it can't create an instance of her self because it ***doesn't*** have a type.It has some methods and keeps the type of classes the implements her. So you can create only reference variables and they refers to an object and sure the class of the object must implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as in

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

List is an interface, ArrayList an implementing class.
This hides the implementation (class), and offers only the requirement/contract (interface). That is a sound way of programming, as you may exchange ArrayList with LinkedList (if you have not many strings in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create an instance of an interface, you create an instance of a class which implements an interface.

e.g.

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

The `Map` is an interface and `LinkedHashMap` is a class which implements an interface.